# Nokogiri: ids Vs hierarchy xpath performance

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have to write down the xml schema for a dataset which is hierarchically organized. It has to be parsed by Nokogiri for information retrieval. My question is, under a performance point of view, is it better to respect the hierarchy or to flatten it? 
E.g.

```
<item_1 id="id_1">
  <item_2 id="id_2">value</item_2>
</item_1>
```

or

```
<item id_1="id_2" id_2="id_2">value</item>
```

I know that multiple attributes should be avoided as far as readability and maintainability are concerned, but performance is my priority.

Comment: Performance of what? It depends on what you are going to do with the document.

Comment: It also depends on the size of the document.

Comment: My bad, the operations that are likely to be performed are "select all the items where id_1=x and id_2=y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the absolute fastest performance and the documents are large, you probably don't want to use XPath at all. A SAX (or Reader) filter will be the fastest.

But if you are going to have Nokogiri parse the document and create a DOM for XPath, I don't think it will make much difference whether you query using:

```ruby
doc.xpath('/item1[@id=x]/item2[@id=y]') #first case
```

or

```ruby
doc.xpath('/item[@id_1=x and @id2=y]') #second case
```

Of course, benchmarking these two solutions against your real data is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: I thought too that the performances would be almost the same, I just wanted have a second opimiom. Unluckily at this stage of the project I do not have access to the real data, I will try to make some toy examples to benchmark the thing.

Comment: Also, if you're going for pure query speed, don't recreate a DOM each time. Create it once and reuse it for queries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: Technically, it's just an accepted answer. Bounties have a different meaning on SO. (but thanks :) )